# Why didn't DIO used his piercing eye attack to kill Joseph or Jotaro?

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

When DIO stops time to kill Joseph, he uses a knife. But why didn't he use his piercing eye attack? The same goes for when fighting Jotaro: he doesn't use it and uses a police officer's gun or knives instead.

Comment: One world arrogance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My real-world explanation is simply that Araki forgot. However, my lore-friendly answer is that Dio either wasn't capable of using his Vampiric abilities because of Jonathan's body, or that he simply didn't care to because he was virtually invincible with The World.

Answer (score 0):

The laser eye attack was so strong decapitated him last time he used it and he needs Jonathan's body to kill Jotaro. His vampire powers also became less and less as his stand ability became more and more.

Comment: Not really. DIO, part 3 Dio to be exact, wasn't fully vampire. He had the body of a Joestar that used Hamon. Hamon, as we know, is a vampire purifier. It turns vampires into regular humans before murdering them. If his vampire powers became less, than wouldn't he get to a point where he wouldn't be able to suck blood? That's not how vampires work. Also, if his vampire powers were weakening, then shouldn't his normal vampire strength decrease? This would mean his stamina decreases, which totally contradicts the point of DIO's timestop increasing due to vampires having increased stamina. Your po

Comment: -int just doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Since Dio is a vampire, And he fused with Jonathan’s body. But. Since Jonathan was a hamon user it weakened Dio when he fused body’s, we can easily tell he got weakened and he got a stand ability, as we see in the scenes, Dio sucks many peoples blood healing his neck wound further and also growing his stand ability, but since Dio had the ultimate stand The World he most likely thought that vampiric abbilitys were outdated and weak. I still do not see why Dio used a police officers gun instead of Space Ripper Stingy Eyes/ Essence Lasers. This is my thought.